# How to add images within texts that stored in sqlite in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I want to add some images between the texts. I stored texts in sqlite db. How can I determine the right location of images in texts. For example, I have 5 paragraphs in one lesson that I stored all those paragraphs in one cell of a row in db named body_of_lesson. Now I want to add an image after line 3 of first paragraph and 1 image after second paragraph. How can I determine these locations and add images into the locations? In other lessons might be vary the locations. I saved texts as HTML formatted into the database.

Please help me !!

Comment: Build your own markup parser and your own mark standard for your app. There is no standard way or preferred way of doing this because its up to your implementation.

Comment: you want text like  ``xxxxImagexxxx`` ?

Comment: @DonaldWu  yes partly,

Comment: @Enzokie , Well for large texts, isn't this way slow down the runtime execution?

Comment: You need to use threads for that.

Answer (score 0):

use image ref in your html. e.g. `<a href="file:///**"`, which ** is the image path stored in sqlite.